# Print total rendering time after a long script of several image renders?

Tags: python

This wouldn't be for animation, but variations in color and view angle for the same object. So all renders are on frame 1 (in case that matter).

It would just need to add together the rendering time of each images at the end of the script. I have no idea how to do just that though, and how to access the rendering duration info from python in Blender.

Comment: If you don't need it down to the millisecond that is used for the actual rendering without building the BVH etc., then I'd suggest to use `import time`, measure the time once before rendering, then after and check of much time has passed. Would that solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is a bit incomplete but usually the time module is used, then

```
import bpy , time

def yourFunction(self,context):

    start = time.time()
    ####your script
    ####
    ####
    stop = time.time()

    result = stop-start

    print("Your time is :"+"{:05.2f}".format(result)+" Seconds")
```

note "{:05.2f}".format(result) It is used to format the seconds by approximating the cent